# (node:1184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, pgadmin

Im trying yo connect NODE.JS with Postgresql and PGAdmin V4.5. I have this error

> > (node:1184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
> > at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

I tried to fixed it using DATABASE_URL in my config file but It dosn't work.

This is my config file.

```
module.exports = {
  DATABASE_URL: "192.168.x.xx",
  HOST: "192.168.x.xx",
  PORT: "5432",
  USER: "postgres",
  PASSWORD: "xxxxx",
  DB: "public",
  dialect: "postgres",
};
```

Controller

```
const db = require("../config/db.config");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const pool = new Pool(db);

// Retrieve all noticias from the database.
const getNews = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = pool.query("select * from noticias");
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred.",
    });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getNews,
};
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});

// set port, listen for requests
require("./routes/noticias.routes")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Routes

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  const noticias = require("../controllers/noticias.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  router.get("/", noticias.getNews);

  app.use("/noticias", router);
};
```

EDIT: I changed the config to lowercase and now I have another problem. When I try to make a SQL query I recieve this error:

> > (node:312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no existe la relación «noticias»

Comment: Please, can you add the node.js connection code to postgresql

Answer (score 2):

After lot of research, I found that, if we want to connect from container to container, instead of using `localhost` as *POSTGRES_HOST*, use `container_name` of the postgres container as the host in the service where u want to use postgres.

Below is the example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  postgres:
    container_name: "metadata_db.postgres"
    image: "metadata_db:test"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  rabbitmq3:
    container_name: "rabbitmq.postgres"
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    expose:
      - 15672
      - 5672
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
    healthcheck:
      test:  rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5

  restful_api:
    container_name: "restapi.postgres"
    image: restful_api:test
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbitmq3:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST=metadata_db.postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - AMQP_HOST=rabbitmq.postgres
      - AMQP_USER=guest
      - AMQP_PASSWORD=guest
      - AMQP_PORT=5672
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

volumes:
  postgres-volume:
```

Comment: Now working in container but how to do this dynamically. When I am working locally and for that it won't be able to search for `postgres_cont_name` in my local env (bcz that is for docker and not my env).

Comment: Run it with network_mode as 'host' and you will be able to access it with Machine's IP

Answer (score 0):

Do not use uppercase variables name in `db.config`

`db.config.js` corrected:

```
module.exports = {
  host: "192.168.x.xx",
  port: "5432",
  user: "postgres",
  password: "xxxxx",
  db: "public",
  dialect: "postgres",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - what fixed it for me was setting the correct environment variables:

```
PGDATABASE=[database]
PGUSER=[user]
PGPASSWORD=[password]
```

and updating DB_HOST from `localhost` to

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```